# Google People API - standard eg has compile error

Tags: java, gradle, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have tried the following Google People API eg:

https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java

and the Gradle build step fails with a compilation error:

> import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleScopes;   not found;

Can anyone tell me the correct line here,
or is there a dependency missing from the Gradle Build file shown in the example.
build gradle dependencies below:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
  compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev140-1.22.0' 
}
```

Comment: You got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

First, go to the source file and delete the import statement.

Next, go to the line that was using the PeopleScopes enum.
 It should be something to the effect of:

```
Arrays.asList(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
```

Change PeopleScopes to PeopleServiceScopes so the new line reads:

```
Arrays.asList(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);
```

This should fix your problem